# Button click counter not functioning properly

Tags: java, swing

I have built a GUI that counts the number of clicks. The problem is that when i press the reset button and then click increment it keeps adding up to the old counter. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
private class MyEventHandler implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField counter;
    private int clicks;

    public MyEventHandler(JTextField counter)
    {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getSource() == increment)
        {   
            clicks++;
            counter.setText("Number of increments: " + clicks);

        }
        else if (event.getSource() == reset)
        {
            clicks = 0;
            counter.setText("Number of increments: " + clicks);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `if (event.getSource() == reset)` returns `true` if you click the reset button?

Comment: yes because it then displays Number of increments: 0

Comment: Try initializing `clicks` in the constructor to `0` as `this.clicks = 0;`!

Comment: In general is not a good practice using == on objects. Which objects are increment and reset (i suppose JButton) and where are they defined ? Can you post the classes ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need your `clicks` variable as `static`. Static variables are shared among all objects and therefore, `clicks` will be resettled for every event handler when `getSource() == reset`.

Or

You can give common action listener to both buttons:

```
MyEventHandler meh = new MyEventHandler();
increment.setActionListener(meh);
reset.setActionListener(meh);
```

Comment: `clicks` is a private member which can easily be accessed in public method. so whats the need to make it static?

Comment: It is not about `private` or `public` access. See when you click on increment button, you increment clicks for that button and show. However, when you reset, you only reset clicks for reset button and not for increment button. Therefore, your increment button counts up from old count.

Comment: Thanks i was just adding the buttons to 2 different ActionListener objects

Comment: Happy :) to help.